# Stuck with an SQL join query

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm making a Q&A site, similar to this site and Yahoo answers. I have 3 tables - smf_members, qa_questions and qa_answers.

In this query, I want to select some fields from qa_questions, a few fields from smf_members and the number of records in ga_answers for the question_id. This is so I can have some basic info on the question, some basic info on the member, and the number of answers.

This is the query I've produced so far and it almost works, but doesn't return questions with which have no answers (ie, no records in the answers table for this question_id).

```
SELECT qa_questions.question_id, 
       qa_questions.question_title, 
       qa_questions.question_content, 
       qa_questions.time_asked, 
       qa_questions.question_author, 
       qa_questions.votes, 
       qa_questions.views, 
       qa_questions.pretty_url, 
       smf_members.real_name, 
       smf_members.id_member, 
       COUNT(qa_answers.question_id) AS answers 
FROM   qa_questions, 
       qa_answers, 
       smf_members 
WHERE  qa_questions.deleted = 0 
       AND smf_members.id_member = qa_questions.question_author 
       AND qa_answers.question_id = qa_questions.question_id 
ORDER  BY qa_questions.time_asked DESC 
LIMIT  10
```

Comment: Related: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `qa_answers` table:

```
SELECT q.question_id, 
    q.question_title, 
    q.question_content, 
    q.time_asked, 
    q.question_author, 
    q.votes, 
    q.views, 
    q.pretty_url, 
    m.real_name, 
    m.id_member, 
    COUNT(a.question_id) as answers 
FROM qa_questions q
inner join smf_members m on m.id_member = q.question_author 
left outer join qa_answers a on a.question_id = q.question_id 
WHERE q.deleted = 0 
ORDER BY q.time_asked DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: That appears to do the exact same thing as my current query. I also just noticed that both these queries only ever return one question. If I add more answers (for different question ID's), it just increases the answer count of the one returned question.

Comment: @Matt: `qa_answers` is being joined by `question_id`, so answer count for one question when answers are added to another question can not increase due to that. You may find additional questions not showing if either `q.q.question_author` is null or there is no matching value in `m.id_member`.

Comment: The members part should be fine, because I'm using the same author ID for all questions+answers. When I add answers for any question that exists, all the answers are added to the one question that shows. If I add an answer for a non-existent question, the answer count does not increment. Could you possibly review your query and suggest any changes which may help? This is a bit out of my depth now, and I'm not too sure what's going on with the joins.. =/

Comment: Best thing would be to post your schema.

Answer (score 2):

You need a GROUP BY clause to group the number of answers per question

```
...
GROUP BY q.question_id
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Oh my.. that worked perfectly, thank you so much! Now I don't know which to pick as the answer..

Answer (score 0):

A previous answer of mine might help, although it didn't get any up votes or accepted so it's probably worthless :P

[MySQL Left Join with conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564781/mysql-left-join-with-conditional/3565724#3565724)

Comment: Okay cheers, I'll try to modify that to my set up if I can't get the above working.